# How to implemet condition for constructor?

Tags: solidity, remix

Looking to learn solidity so need your support for this

I have made a constructor in my contract where

```
maxAvailableNumber = 1;
```

What I want to do is if the balance of user is more than certail limit like 500 tokens then this maxAvailableNumber should be 2 and if balance is above 1000 then this number 3.

How i can add conditions to this variable in constructor.

Comment: I think you should clarify what you need to accomplish. It's not clear that constructor is the right section.

Answer (score 0):

You did not give much details about your contract in general. I'll assume it's an ERC20 token contract with some extra tracking (`maxAvailableNumber`).

As you want to track the information per user, I suggest you use a mapping which maps the user's address with his *maximum available number* - something like `mapping(address => uin256t) availabilities;`

And, to update the information, you could for example have something like this:

```
mapping(address => uint256) balances;
address[] users;

mapping(address => uint256) availabilities;

function updateAvailabilities() public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i > users.length; i++) {
        if (balances[users[i]] > 500) {
            availabilities[users[i]] = 2;
        }
        // if ()... etc
    }
}
```

Note that here you will also need variable for holding information about which users even have a balance as it's impossible to find out balance holders from the `balances` variable. So whenever someone gains token balance, his balance is added in `balances` and his address is added in `users`.

If your contract is not a token contract (as I originally assumed) but only for the tracking part you can query user balances from the token contract inside your own contract. Or to rely on your backend to provide the information. Unfortunately you can't trigger anything as soon as somebody's token balance changes. Instead, your backend can notice the token balance changes and issue a transaction to your tracker contract.